# For loop in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I am new to Oracle and I am unaware about using for loop in Oracle SQL (not PL/SQL).

I had a requirement to increase the number by +1 in the query and execute the statements; is it possible to use a for loop in SQL?

Comment: There are no "for loops" in set operations. Just ask the "real question" - make sure to show input/output/current attempt - and make sure the title reflects it. Remove the `plsql` tag if it is indeed *not PL/SQL* as described.

Comment: As pst said, there are no "for loops" but there are ways to achieve the same effect. What do you mean by *execute the statements* and which number should be increased by 1 and how many times ?

Comment: @A.B.Cade i want to create a custom variable say 'i' and i want to increase it until it reaches '5' i want to use this variable to append to some string . is it possible in sql

Comment: @user964147, can you update your post to have an example of your data and required output ? do you mean something like [this](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8/7871)?

Comment: If you want to generate a result set with increasing number, and add to some other query, insert, try this:    
Select Rownum r
From dual
Connect By Rownum <= 5

Comment: You can also use row_number [like this](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/8fda0/2). You really should [edit] your question as pst described

Comment: This is absolutely a real question IMO. Closing it is simply wrong. What's wrong with asking if there is a possibility of doing a FOR LOOP in SQL? That's pretty spot-on and I worked on it a while ago. Doing it in Oracle SQL is definitely possible.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You are pretty confused my friend. There are no LOOPS in SQL, only in PL/SQL. Here's a few examples based on existing Oracle table - copy/paste to see results:

```
-- Numeric FOR loop --
set serveroutput on -->> do not use in TOAD --
DECLARE
  k NUMBER:= 0;
BEGIN
  FOR i IN 1..10 LOOP
    k:= k+1;
    dbms_output.put_line(i||' '||k);
 END LOOP;
END;
/

-- Cursor FOR loop --
set serveroutput on
DECLARE
   CURSOR c1 IS SELECT * FROM scott.emp;
   i NUMBER:= 0;
BEGIN
  FOR e_rec IN c1 LOOP
  i:= i+1;
    dbms_output.put_line(i||chr(9)||e_rec.empno||chr(9)||e_rec.ename);
  END LOOP;
END;
/

-- SQL example to generate 10 rows --
SELECT 1 + LEVEL-1 idx
  FROM dual
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 10
/
```

Answer (score 3):

You will certainly be able to do that using *WITH clause*, or use *analytic functions* available in Oracle SQL.

With some effort you'd be able to get anything out of them in terms of cycles as in ordinary procedural languages. Both approaches are pretty powerful compared to ordinary SQL.

http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_with_clause.htm

http://www.orafaq.com/node/55

It requires some effort though. Don't be afraid to post a concrete example.

Using simple pseudo table DUAL helps too.

Comment: i have edited my question please have a look at the example

Comment: sorry, can't see it. 'wise' guys closed the question too early, probably, because they did not understand it.

Comment: Could you post another question? Frame it as 'how to do this using Oracle SQL analytic functions'? that way they won't close it.

Comment: I have posted another question that represents the problem. Please have a look at here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15014802/how-to-apply-kind-of-loop-for-this-oracle-query